# How to use an IF function to update columns in a data frame?

Tags: r

```
predict <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  0         1 
  0.44      0.55     
  0.76      0.24     
  0.71      0.29    
  0.75      0.24 
  0.25      0.75
")
```

I have attached a sample data frame with 2 columns titled '0' & '1'. I want to use an IF function so that if the value in the 0 column is bigger than 0.7 the cell updates to have a 0 value in it. Also if the value in the '1' column is bigger than 0.7 the cell updates to have a 1 value in it. Finally if neither the '0' or '1' values are bigger than 0.7 I would like the cells to return as -99. I have attached an example of what my sample would look like after this IF function was applied.

```
predict <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
      0         1 
      -99      -99     
      0        0.24     
      0        0.29    
      0        0.24 
      0.25     1
    ")
```

The code I have attempted is;

```
if(predict[,1] > 0.7 ){predict[,1] == '0' }
if(predict[,1] > 0.7 ){predict[,2] == '1' }
```

If you could advise me on the best way to update this IF function that would be really appreciated.

Comment: It is a very good question, yet it sounds so simple and straight forward at first but modifying 2 columns in place based on multiple conditions may be sometimes tricky.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Based on the intervention of AniGoyal (Many thanks for this!!!)
I updated the answer to fulfill the exact desired output of the OP:
I combined the two answers in one code to get the desired output:

Code:

```
predict %>%
  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(a =  case_when(X0 > 0.7 ~ 0,
                         TRUE ~ ifelse(X0 < 0.7 & X1 < 0.7, -99, X0)),
         b =  case_when(X1 > 0.7 ~ 1,
                         TRUE ~ ifelse(X1 < 0.7 & X0 < 0.7, -99, X1))
         ) %>% 
  select(X0 = a, X1=b)
```

Output:

```
      X0      X1
   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 -99    -99    
2   0      0.24 
3   0      0.290
4   0      0.24 
5   0.25   1
```

We could use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package. `Mutate` changes columns `X0` and `X1` depending on den `case_when` condition.

```
library(dplyr)

predict %>% 
  mutate(X0 = case_when(X0 > 0.7 ~ 0,
                        TRUE ~ -99),
         X1 = case_when(X1 > 0.7 ~ 1,
                        TRUE ~ -99)
  )
```

Output:

```
   X0  X1
1 -99 -99
2   0 -99
3   0 -99
4   0 -99
5 -99   1
```

**ifelse**

Or we could use `ifelse` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse

```
predict$X0 <- ifelse(predict$X0 > 0.7, 0, -99)
predict$X1 <- ifelse(predict$X1 > 0.7, 1, -99)
predict
```

Comment: Always a pleasure brother.

Comment: The output you are getting is not matching with the requirements, please recheck

Comment: Thank you very much AnilGoyal. I have updated the answer. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Note - numeric names for columns are less desirable ("0" and "1"). Here they are renamed to "X0" and "X1".

One approach with base R is to subset your data for your 3 circumstances, first checking to see if neither are greater than .7 (and set both to -99), then checking the 0 column (set to 0), then checking the 1 column (set to 1):

```
predict[!(predict$X0 > .7 | predict$X1 > .7), c("X0", "X1")] <- -99
predict[predict$X0 > .7, "X0"] <- 0
predict[predict$X1 > .7, "X1"] <- 1
predict
```

**Output**

```
      X0     X1
1 -99.00 -99.00
2   0.00   0.24
3   0.00   0.29
4   0.00   0.24
5   0.25   1.00
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just another way using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

predict %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(X0 = ifelse(X0 > 0.7, 0, X0),
         X1 = ifelse(X1 > 0.7, 1, X1)) %>%
  mutate(across(X0:X1, ~ ifelse((X0 < 0.7 & X0 != 0) & (X1 < 0.7 & X0 != 0), -99, .)))

       X0      X1
   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 -99    -99    
2   0      0.24 
3   0      0.290
4   0      0.24 
5   0.25   1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in the code you are trying -

- baseR's if else doesn't work iteratively.  So If you have to use that for a complete vector where each element is to be checked iteratively, you'll have to use it inside a loop
- usage of `==` for assignment.  `==` is used for comparision/conditionals and not for assignment.  Use `=` for assignment.

If you still want to do it baseR's if else style

```
for(i in 1:nrow(predict)){
  if(predict[i, 1] > 0.7){
    predict[i, 1] = 0
  }
  if(predict[i,2] > 0.7){
    predict[i, 2] = 1
  }
  if(predict[i, 1] < 0.7 & predict[i, 2] < 0.7 & predict[i, 1] >0){
    predict[i, 1] = -99
    predict[i, 2] = -99
  }
}

> predict
      X0     X1
1 -99.00 -99.00
2   0.00   0.24
3   0.00   0.29
4   0.00   0.24
5   0.25   1.00
```

You may also consider use of `replace` like this

```
predict[, 1] <- replace(predict[,1], predict[,1] > 0.7, 0)
predict[, 2] <- replace(predict[,2], predict[,2] > 0.7, 1)
predict[, 1] <- replace(predict[, 1], predict[, 2] < 0.7 & predict[, 1] < 0.7 & predict[, 1] > 0, -99)
predict[, 2] <- replace(predict[, 2], predict[, 2] < 0.7 & predict[, 1] < 0.7 & predict[, 1] > 0, -99)

> predict
      X0   X1
1 -99.00 0.55
2   0.00 0.24
3   0.00 0.29
4   0.00 0.24
5   0.25 1.00
```

Comment: The last output using `replace` does not match the OP's desired output. Anyway very good solution (upvote!)